# css: how to align left last line/row of content

Tags: css, alignment, center

I have div with centered content - an images, but the problem is that last line is also centered and it broke the "grid effect"

```
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="iB"></div>
    <div class="iB"></div>
    <div class="iB"></div>
    <div class="iB"></div>
    <div class="iB"></div>
    <div class="iB"></div>
    <div class="iB"></div>
    <div class="iB"></div>
    <div class="iB"></div>
    <div class="iB"></div>
    <div class="iB"></div>
    <div class="iB"></div>
    <div class="iB"></div>
    <div class="iB"></div>
    <div class="iB"></div>
    <div class="iB"></div>
    <div class="iB"></div>
    <div class="iB"></div>
    <div class="iB"></div>
    <div class="iB"></div>
    <div class="iB"></div>
    <div class="iB"></div>
    <div class="iB"></div>
    <div class="iB"></div>
    <div class="iB"></div>
</div>

.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    text-align: center;
}


.iB {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: green;
    padding: 2%;
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/puz219/zaBux/

how to align last line/row to the left?

thank you in advanced

Comment: Using Flexbox is probably about as close as you're going to be able to get, and even then the result isn't very good:  http://tinker.io/ce346.  Mozilla does have a proprietary CSS property specifically for targeting the alignment of the last line, but I have no idea what the name of it is.

Comment: You can align the last line by adding several spacers to the content: http://jsfiddle.net/zaBux/10/.

Answer (score 1):

it's caused by `text-align: center`. on `.wrapper`.

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    width: calc(100%-10px);
    background: red;
    padding: 5px;
}


.iB {
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 2px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: green;
    padding: 2%;
}
```

Change `calc(100%-10px)` to just `100%` if you need it to work in IE. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zaBux/4/

Comment: i know, because i want to content will be centered, but except last line - it shoul "fits the grid"

Comment: @PuZ See the fiddle. You can't keep it centered without a fixed number of `<div>`s per row.

Comment: i can't fix the number of divs per row because the whole layout is resizable so this number will dynamically changes

Answer (score 0):

try this in your css

```
.iB:last-child{text-align:left}
```

Comment: it's not working because :last-child reffers to the very last element not the whole line

Comment: `.iB {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: green;
    padding: 2%;float:left
}` and play with margin

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can't with the actual CSS specficiation.

But there is hacky way, working on all browsers :

- create a new class with the same properties of your elements, but with a height of 0px
- add a lot of  at the bottom of your wrapper, to 'fill' the line

I update your fiddle : `http://jsfiddle.net/zaBux/9/` , and it's working (maybe you will have to add more div elements to cover large width screen)

In the future, you will be able do it only with CSS, with the multiple `:after` pseudo selector (http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/#inserting0)

W3C specified a first-line selector but not yet a last-line one

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a bunch of media queries to get this to work.

We apply a width to the wrapper div at each screen width that can hold an additional box

Now that we have a set width it's easy to center it now with `margin: 0 auto`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/SdyeP/2/)**

### CSS

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}


.iB {
    float:left;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: green;
    margin: 10px;
}
@media (max-width: 70px) { /* 70 = 50 + 10 + 10 (left and right margins) */
    .wrapper{
        width: 70px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 140px) {
    .wrapper{
        width: 140px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 210px) {
    .wrapper{
        width: 210px;
    }
}
etc etc.
```